# Wrong value returned from radio buttons

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a radio button which has two values, "2-takt" and "4-takt", but it always returns the value "2-takt" not matter if I choose "4-takt". How can I fix this?

This is code in the .php file:

```
<div class="form-group-radio">
                                <label for="scooter-version" class="control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('scooter_version'); ?> **</label>
                                <input type="radio" name="version" value="2-Takt" id="scooter-version" class="radio-control" /> 2-Takt
                                <input type="radio" name="version" value="4-Takt" id="scooter-version" class="radio-control" /> 4-Takt
                            </div>
```

And here is the code in the .js file:

```
        var postData = new Object();

    postData['customer'] = {
        'last_name': $('#last-name').val(),
        'first_name': $('#first-name').val(),
        'email': $('#email').val(),
        'phone_number': $('#phone-number').val(),
        'address': $('#address').val(),
        'city': $('#city').val(),
        'zip_code': $('#zip-code').val(),
        'scooter_brand': $('#scooter-brand').val(),
        'scooter_type': $('#scooter-type').val(),
        'scooter_version': $('#scooter-version').val()
    };
```

Is there anything specific I need to do with values obtained from radio buttons?

Comment: oh, I didn't even notice. I Removed the tag.

Comment: `id`s need to be unique. Do not use an ID on multiple elements. For that purpose, you have classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:checked` selector:

```
...
'scooter_version': $('input:radio[name="version"]:checked').val()
...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. It still didn't fix the problem. Could there be anything else? If not I will have to try and find the error myself. Thanks again!

Comment: @WiscomJ, are you getting the checked radio value via `name` or `id` attribute?

Comment: ids are supposed to be unique. two tags shouldn't have the same id

Comment: I am getting the value via the `name` attribute

Comment: strange, what does `console.log(postData['customer'])` show before ajax is sent?

Comment: Argh, stupid. Somehow the file did not save correctly. It is working now. Thanks Roman!